# JApplet keybinding printscreen

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, japplet, printscreen

My objective is to have the printscreen key trigger my application to close (ideally before it can actually copy to clipboard, but not important) I have other keybindings working- but I cannot figure out how to trigger printscreen. In the below code, if I replace "VK_PRINTSCREEN" w/ "VK_M" (or another key) the letter m closes the app - having the functionality that I desire. Any suggestions on how to properly call printscreen? or any other ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
 private void bindKeys() {
            JRootPane rp = getRootPane();
            int c = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
            InputMap inputMap = rp.getInputMap(c);
            ActionMap actionMap = rp.getActionMap();
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "UP");
            actionMap.put("UP", upAction);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "DOWN");
            actionMap.put("DOWN", downAction);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN,0),"PRINT"); 
            actionMap.put("PRINT", rightAction);
        }
     private AbstractAction upAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("UP");
            }
        };

        private AbstractAction downAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("DOWN");
            }
        };

        private AbstractAction rightAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("PRINT");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
```

Comment: A `JApplet` should never call `System.exit(n)`!

Comment: I'll navigate to another page instead - just wanted to mock up an example.